# Grouping limited records and the rest group as other

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

Is there any way to group data like

```
df.Feature.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

but instead of give the entire records just give me like the first 5 and the rest of records group as "others"

For example this is the output I get when running the code above

```
NUEVO LEON          9.566025
ESTADO DE MEXICO    8.979984
TAMAULIPAS          7.939926
VERACRUZ            7.686035
DISTRITO FEDERAL    7.257108
COAHUILA            5.283328
JALISCO             4.835284
BAJA CALIFORNIA     4.280905
MICHOACAN           4.160830
GUANAJUATO          4.129765
```

An this is the output I am looking for

```
NUEVO LEON          9.566025
ESTADO DE MEXICO    8.979984
TAMAULIPAS          7.939926
VERACRUZ            7.686035
DISTRITO FEDERAL    7.257108
OTHERS              24.56156
```

Comment: Do you want to group anything less than 5 as 'OTHERS' and sum the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just do this after the `value_counts` as the result will be sorted descending. Given the Series `s`, the result of `df.Feature.value_counts(normalize=True)`, you can keep the first 5, then sum everything else.

```
import pandas as pd

N = 5
pd.concat([s.iloc[:N], pd.Series(s.iloc[N:].sum(), index=['OTHERS'])])
#NUEVO LEON           9.566025
#ESTADO DE MEXICO     8.979984
#TAMAULIPAS           7.939926
#VERACRUZ             7.686035
#DISTRITO FEDERAL     7.257108
#OTHERS              22.690112
#dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with creating a temporary column for this you can do:

```py
# where keep_list = the list of values not in "other"
df['temp'] = df['Feature'].copy()
df.loc[~df['temp'].isin(keep_list), 'temp'] = 'Other'
df['temp'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
import pandas as pd


sample_grouped = pd.DataFrame({'location': ["NUEVO LEON", "ESTADO DE MEXICO", "TAMAULIPAS", "VERACRUZ", "DISTRITO FEDERAL", "COAHUILA", "JALISCO", "BAJA CALIFORNIA", "MICHOACAN", "GUANAJUATO"],
                               'amount': [9.566025, 8.979984, 7.939926, 7.686035, 7.257108, 5.283328, 4.835284, 4.280905, 4.160830, 4.129765]})

top_5 = sample_grouped[:5]

others = sample_grouped[5:]

others_total = others.iloc[:,[1]].sum()[0]

result = pd.DataFrame.append(top_5, pd.DataFrame({'location': ['OTHERS'], 'amount': [others_total]}))
```